# ReactTable component is not rendering data coming from api,If i use hardcoded data it is showing

Tags: reactjs

I am using reacttable-6 to render the data in table,but the is not showing up in table.It is giving me "No data found".Data is coming from api,even i console logged the response from api,the what data i am getting from  is fine.I aslo hard coded the data,then the data is showing up in the table

I am not able to figure out what the issue is.Thanks inadvance.

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import ReactTable from "react-table-6";
import 'react-table-6/react-table.css';
import axios from "axios";

export default function Inventory(){

  var compdata = [
    {
      FirstName: "Chandu",
      LastName: "Reddy",
      _id: "63c5766f9d9de1b624481574",

      Discription: {
        _id: "63c5766f9d9de1b624481574",
        DOB: "Havells",
        Age: "HiBreak",
       
      },
      Address: "Something",
    
    }
 
  ];

  const handleDelete=(data)=>{
  
    console.log(data)
  }
  const handleEdit=()=>{
  
    console.log("dcdc")
  }
  
  
  
  
    const column = [
      {
        Header: "FirstName",
        accessor: "FirstName",
        sortable: false
      },
      {
        Header: "LastName",
        accessor: "LastName",
        sortable: false
      },
      {
        Header: "Address",
        accessor: "Address",
        sortable: false
      },
      {
        Header: "Actions",
        Cell: (row) => (
          <div>
            <a onClick={() => handleEdit(row.original)}>
              Edit
            </a>
            <a onClick={() => handleDelete(row.original)}>
              Delete
            </a>
          </div>
        )
      }
    ];
  
 

    const [data1, setData1] = useState([]);
    const [columns, setColumns] = useState(column);
    const { toggle } = useContext(ThemeContext);
    useEffect(()=>{

      const fetch = async () => {

        await axios
          .get(`http://localhost:4001/api/uploadCsv/getData`)
          .then((res) => {

            setData1(res.data);
            console.log(res.data)
   
       
          });
      };
      fetch();

    },[setData1]);


    const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState({});
  
    const onExpandedChange = (newExpanded) => {
      setExpanded(newExpanded);
    };
 

    return(
        <div className="container">

            
                <div className='Table-container'>
                  
                <ReactTable
        data={data1}
        columns={columns}
        defaultPageSize={data1.length}
        showPagination={false}
        resizable={false}
        expanded={expanded}
        // className="-striped -highlight"
        getTrProps={(state, rowInfo, column, instance, expanded) => {
          return rowInfo
            ? {
                onClick: (expanded) => {
                  const newExpanded = { ...expanded };
                  newExpanded[rowInfo.viewIndex] = expanded[rowInfo.viewIndex]
                    ? false
                    : true;
                  setExpanded(newExpanded);
                }
              }
            : {};
        }}
        SubComponent={(row) => {
          return (
            <div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
              <em>{(row.original.Discription.Make)}</em>K              <br />
            </div>
          );
        }}
      />
      <br />
  
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

[Screen shot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5Kf3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change your useEffect like this and add another to check did data1 updated yet.  Depend on data1 have value or not we will have different way to solve this

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get(`http://localhost:4001/api/uploadCsv/getData`).then((res) => {
    setData1(res.data);
  });
}, []);

useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(data1)
},[data1])
```

Comment: Yes! Data1 is updated.Its has value